# How to cancel a scheduled job in sidekiq. How to fetch jid of a scheduled job from my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

job = HardWorker.perform_in(2.minutes, arg1, arg2)

j_id = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find { |job_id| job.job_id }.item["jid"]

I get the following error :
NoMethodError: undefined method `job_id' for "6512497a4359600501f63038":String

What is the correct way to fetch job id and delete the scheduled job?

Answer (score 1):

[From Sidekiq wiki FAQ](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-cancel-a-sidekiq-job)

> **How do I cancel a Sidekiq job?**
>
> Sidekiq does not provide this functionality; it's safer and better for the application to do it. You should implement something like this:
>
> ```
> class MyWorker
>   include Sidekiq::Worker
>
>   def perform(args)
>     return if cancelled?
>     # do stuff
>   end
>
>   def cancelled?
>     Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.exists("cancelled-#{jid}") } # Use c.exists? on Redis >= 4.2.0
>   end
>
>   def self.cancel!(jid)
>     Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.setex("cancelled-#{jid}", 86400, 1) }
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: I have tried this. Doesnt seem to cancel the job. I still see it on the dashboard.Not sure what I have missed